# Creating function to call api for pagination is calling duplicate value int

Tags: python, json, django, api, request

I am building a simple app in `react` and `django` in which I am accessing `API` and paginating in the backend.

The Problem is that, I want to make two calls on per page click, for example - If user clicked on page 1 then I am trying to make api call with page `&page=1` and `&page=2`.
And If user clicked on page 2 then make api call `&page=3` and `&page=4` and If user clicked on page 3 then make api call `&page=5` and `&page=6`

But the problem is that When user is on page `1st` then it is making api calls (page 1 and 2) finely But when User moves to page 2 then it is calling api with `&page=2` and `&page=3` instead of `&page=3` and `&page=4`.

I want to call api for next two pages.

views.py

```
class MakeApiCall(APIView):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        current_page = self.request.query_params.get('current_page')
        current_page = int(current_page)

        for index in range(2):
            url = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=" + str(current_page)
            call_api = requests.get(url)
            print(call_api.url)
            current_page += 1
```

When I run above function with current_page = 1 then It is calling api with `page=1` and `page=2` but when I call current_page = 2 then It is calling again with `page=2` and `page=3` not `page=3` and `page=4`

I have created while loop just for it But It is working just like this range function.

Every page returns `25 results` so I will stop the loop when Array has 50 items But It is still working just as below function

```
    results = []

    while len(results) != 50:
        url = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=" + str(current_page)
        call_api = requests.get(url)
        for result in api_results.json():
            if len(results) < 50:
                results.append(result)
            else:
                break
```

But It is still calling the api the same way before.

I liked the `while` method, It would be best but not working.

Frontend is fine but if you need it then please let me know

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly you could add `current_page = current_page+1 if current_page != 1 else current_page` right under your `current_page = int(current_page)` and that would make that `range()` loop correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `index` isn't used in the `for` loop to fetch the appropriate pages. Instead, you're fetching the current page and the next one, which is the behavior you observed. In the `while` loop, `current_page` is fetched 50 times, without any incrementation.

We can use a simple formula for determining the start index of the loop: `current_page * 2 - 1` (you can manually check that this works for the cases where `current_page` is 1, 2, 3, etc.).

*(The formula works because on each call to the API, you're fetching a pair of pages, starting from the odd-numbered page.)*

This means the loop in `views.py` should look like the following:

```py
...

for i in range(2):
    start_index = current_page * 2 - 1
    url = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=" + str(start_index + i)
    call_api = requests.get(url)
    print(call_api.url)
```

Comment: you could calculate `start_index` even before `for`-loop

Comment: @furas Yes, but this is what the author originally asked for, and a loop will enable developers to more easily extend the feature in the future :)

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz, Thanks It worked, But Can you explain to me how the formula is determining the page.

Comment: @Dana I added my answers above, I hope things are now clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate

```
index1 = (current_page * 2) - 1
index2 = (current_page * 2)
```

For `current_page = 1` it gives `1, 2`

For `current_page = 2` it gives `3, 4`

For `current_page = 3` it gives `5, 6`

etc.